# Заблокировать ввод с клавиатуры в коносль, библиотека curses

Tags: python, gui, консоль, ui, curses

как запретить ввод в консольное приложение curses? Например, что бы при нажатии на клавиши они не вводились в консоль? Как например здесь, после нажатия на стрелки на клавиатуре они отобразились в консоли, как запретить это?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [mcve] в студию... вероятней всего самым простым решением будет включить `keypad` (на вскидку не скажу, как это сделать в питоньих биндингах).

Answer (score 2):

сам нашел ответ, проблема решается одной строкой кода:

```
curses.noecho()
```

она выключает отображение набираемых символов в консоль.